# showing images in go (golang)

Tags: image, go

I am writing a algorithm in go (golang) that manipulates images and I am wondering, is there a simple way to show images in go (i.e similar to a gui).
The best way would not write a file and show it but just show it using some super simple gui function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go has no GUI support itself.  There are some bindings in various qualities of state on different platforms depending on your target audience.  You will need to find one that suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straightforward to expose a simple web interface using the tools in `net/http`. Just enough javascript on the client side to create the image request URL and you're in business.